# MongoDB: select * from raw which has "1st connector" as 1 of the column

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to write this query in MongoDB `select * from raw`, which has "1st connector" as `1` of the column.

I have written:

```
db.raw.find({},{"1st Connector":1})
```

I am getting the following results:

```
> db.raw.find({},{"1st Connector":1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("548b4e270f02f305e8220370") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("548b4e270f02f305e8220371") }
```

When I write "1st connector" without quotes, I get an error:

```
> db.raw.find({},{1st Connector:1})
2015-02-27T09:50:20.956-0800 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I want to see the actual data, i.e. contents of all these objects. How can I see that?

When I do `db.raw.find()`, I get all the data.

I wrote a similar query and I got the following result:

```
> db.raw.find({},{entityType:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("548b4e270f02f305e8220370"), "entityType" : "parishes" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("548b4e270f02f305e8220371"), "entityType" : "parishes" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("548b4e270f02f305e8220372"), "entityType" : "parishes" }
```

Also, I don't know why am I getting `entityType` in result here.

Answer (score 1):

> I have written : `db.raw.find({},{"1st Connector":1})`

Because your probably don't have field named `"1st Connector"`  in your document.

> I write 1st connector, I get error
> `2015-02-27T09:50:20.956-0800 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Because `1st Connector` should be quoted

> wrote a similar query and I got the following result:
>
> `db.raw.find({},{entityType:1})`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("548b4e270f02f305e8220370"), "entityType" : "parishes" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("548b4e270f02f305e8220371"), "entityType" : "parishes" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("548b4e270f02f305e8220372"), "entityType" : "parishes" }
```

Because your have `entityType` field in your document and the second argument in `find`  is the `projection` argument this is pretty clear in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find)

Comment: Shouldn't the query return an error if "1st Connector" is not present in collection?

Comment: @ArpiShah No it should not. This is **by design**. MongoDB itself is "schemaless" so there is no way that a query can "assume" that property does not exist in some document in the collection or ever will. If you want some additional "Query validation checking" then you need to implement some kind of ODM ( NoSQL speak for ORM ) that will perform this check before the query is issued. With NoSQL the general case is your "schema" is represented in your "model" code, and that has the job of determining such things. Not the datastore. The answer "gave you new knowledge". That's useful, and correct.

Comment: Thank you @Michael9, Neil Lunn. I really appreciate your effort in clearing my doubt.